# AlarmManager, setRepeat but alert only showing once

Tags: java, android

This is my first time trying to make an app that starts on boot and runs in the background, and I'm finding all the possible ways of doing it a little confusing. I need the app to do a quick check of a few things every half hour, and sleep in between, so I settled for using AlarmManager and setRepeating.

In this test I've set it up so a boot receiver sets the alarm, which should run a service every 60 seconds (actual app will be 30+ mins between running this). The service triggers a notification, but when I reboot the phone, the notification only shows up once. I clear it and never see it again.

I'll post the relevant code below. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

AlarmStarter.java

```
 public class AlarmStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final int PERIOD = 60000;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            scheduleAlarms(context);
        }
    }

    static void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt) {

        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent i = new Intent(ctxt, BackService.class);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(ctxt, 0, i, 0);

        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,

        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + PERIOD, PERIOD, pi);
    }
```

BackService.java

```
public class BackService extends Service {

    public BackService() {

        //showNotification("ticker test", "title test", "content test", "http://google.com");
        Log.d("CF", "Starting BackService");
        showNotification("ticker test", "title test", "content test", "http://google.com");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {
        // Code to execute when the service is first created
    }

    public void showNotification(String ticker, String title, String content, String url) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setTicker(ticker)

            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.testapp.test" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application

    android:allowBackup="true"

    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver

    android:name=".AlarmStarter"

    android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity

    android:name=".MainActivity"

    android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service

    android:name=".BackService"

    android:enabled="true"

    android:exported="true" ></service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I had here was that the BackService class I was trying to trigger with the alarm, was extending from the Service class. It should have extended from the BroadcastReceiver class, as only BroadcastReceivers can be triggered by the externally sent alarms.